# Laravel 5 Force Download a pdf File

Tags: php, http, pdf, laravel, laravel-5

**Edited** 
i want to Force Download a pdf File in laravel 5.
in laravel 4 i used the following code:

```
        $file= public_path(). "/site-docs/cv.pdf";
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="cv.pdf"',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary',
        'Content-Length:'.filesize($file),
    );
    return \Response::download($file,"Ahmed Badawy - CV.pdf", $headers);
```

but in laravel 5 that doesn't work.it comes out with this error:

```
Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)
```

also i tried this:

```
return response()->download($file);
```

same error apeared...
what can i do to force a download in laravel 5.

### **I Solved it- Answer is:**

it was a server thing. thanks any way.
you just enable this extension: php_fileinfo.dll in the php.ini file.
then restart the server.

Comment: What do you mean by "force"? What's happening, that its opening in browser instead of being "forced" to download?

Comment: @developerwjk He means the PDF file should be downloaded by prompting the user to save it to their filesystem, rather than to display the PDF within the browser.

Comment: On a side note,  I don't see why this question is downvoted.

Comment: @AdamElsodaney, That's what I thought, but this is beyond your control. Its a user setup thing, how they have their browser and Acrobat setup, which is why I asked. (Unless perhaps you serve it as `application/octet-stream` instead of `application/pdf`)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Remove the headers, they're not necessary. In L5, you can do

```
return response()->download($file, "Ahmed Badawy - CV.pdf");
```

Please [read the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#other-responses).

Comment: i did it like this :
  return response()->download($file);
but it comes out with this error:
Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)

Comment: So *did* you enable the `php_fileinfo` extension?

Comment: thanks man, sorry didn't see the comment. i did what you told me. it worked... thanks very much...