# How Do I return a file for download in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-5

I need to be able to give the user a file for download, and so I created a route (unless I can do the link for a specific user's CV in blade). My files are stored in `storage/app/cv/` directory. I created a route as such:

```
Route::get('test', function() {
    $destinationPath = config('app.CVDestinationPath') . "/static_file.pdf";
    $uploaded = Storage::get($destinationPath);
    return $uploaded;
}
```

However this route is giving me a weird output. I think it is the file but it is converting the file to html or something. Could anyone help me return the file (it could be pdf, doc, or docx, or plain text). My file is not stored in the public directory!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Force Download a pdf File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465434/laravel-5-force-download-a-pdf-file)

Comment: @Dekel yea I attempted to do that way before I posted the question, when I tried doing that code. It says that the file does not exist.

Comment: which file does not exists?

Comment: I am attempting to return a static file, which is stored in the myProject\storage\app\cv directory, It's name is `static_file.pdf`

Answer (score 2):

Because the file is not uploaded in the public directory, you are required to use a storage method for accessing it first before you return a response.

```
$destinationPath = config('app.CVDestinationPath') . "/static_file.pdf";
$uploaded = Storage::get($destinationPath);

return (new \Illuminate\Http\Response($uploaded))->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
```

Make sure to return a header with the content type otherwise the file will not be in an acceptable format.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Response" to help you with the download headers:

```
   <?php

   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
   Route::get('test', function() {
      $destinationPath = config('app.CVDestinationPath') . "/static_file.pdf";
      return response()->download($destinationPath);
   }
   ?>
```

Checkout this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#file-downloads to find out more e.g. `response->file($destinationPath)` forces the browser to display the file (.pdf in your case) to the user using its lokal plugins.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow HolyMarcell, this answer is an exact duplicate of the question that mark this one as duplicate. There is no need for such answers. When you get enough reputation you will be able to mark questions as duplicate. Take the time, give some answers and get the relevant rank for that :)

Comment: Ah... I didn't see the duplicate-mark at all. Still my answer is somewhat more concise than those in the other thread ;)

Comment: @Dekel, I'm missing something here; it's not an exact duplicate at all.

Comment: @ChrisForrence the `response()->download` is the answer, as far as I can tell... which is what exists in the dup

Comment: @Dekel The answer solved the problem in the comments; real problem was `php_fileinfo` not being enabled.

Comment: @ChrisForrence I see the update there, however the accepted answer is exactly the answer to what this question is.

Comment: @Dekel you're wrong, it isn't a duplicate. After doing research, you can not use a return response() for files which are not public, which I kept stressing. You are required to retrieve the file from storage, if anyone does want to look at my solution, I will add it below.