# Show characters instead of displaying the download links from file storage in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, download, file-storage

I upload the files using the following commands in this path (app/files/myfile.*)

```
$file = $request->file;
$filename = $file->store('files');
```

The name of files are hashed and properly stored in the path that I said.
Now I want to send the download link for these files to the browser.

```
$file_name = "yPpRejYz5fwhVQ9j67Ns1b5vrSR6CokncZYH4hAa.zip";
return response()->download(storage_path('app/files/' . $file_name));
```

But the output is displayed as shown below.

[image]

Comment: check answer by @Dencker here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465434/laravel-5-force-download-a-pdf-file